# Dynamically split p in span, jquery

Tags: jquery, substring, html, paragraph

I'm writing some read-more/less functionality for a text, but I came across the next problem.

My steps:
1) getting the content of a text containing div, with multiple paragraphs.

```
    var content =  $heroContent.html();
```

2) I make a substring of the part that is always shown, and a second substring of the full text - the part that is always showing, so actually the hidden part.
(that hidden part will be possible to show or hide by clicking a button)

```
c = content.substr(0, 700)
h = content.substr(700, content.length - roundedLimit)
```

3) I put the second part inside a span with class morecontent, so that I can hide that content and show it.

```
html = c + "<span class='morecontent'>" + h + "</span>";
```

4)I add the html variable above again to my div with text, and make the 'morecontent' hide.

Reason for putting the text in a span is that it can be placed inline with the text before where it broke up. If not in span, the text just appears in the line below, which is not wanted.

The problem: the second substring *h*, can consist of multiple paragraphs. So when a P tag closes inside variable *h*, the span tag automatically closes also, hence, the class *morecontent* only applied to the start of the span till the end of the first paragraph inside.

I tried to fix it with putting the text in a DIV, but then the text doesn't appear inline, and that's really an important 'feature'.

If anyone could give me a fix for this problem, that would be great!

Comment: Do you have the ability to play with the container? Something like getting a fixed height with `overflow: hidden` and eventually sliding the container open when someone wants to read everything. A bit like the movie description in YouTube...

Comment: This sounds like a more logical solution then what I was doing :). Thank you! 
I should try to find a way to keep the line height in mind, though, so I don't cut off the container in the middle of a line. Thanks!

Comment: I like to add a soft shadow to (above) the cutoff line so I don't have to worry about it cutting a line in half, the effect is nice and the hint to "more" text available is very subtle and effective.

Comment: I'll try it, but I'm not sure if this will fit into the current design. But in other cases this can help the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that wraps content in a container, and uses a more/less button to expand/contract the container to show the content:

```
var content = $('.content').wrapInner('<div class="moreless less">');

$('.moreless').after('<div class="showbutton"><span>More</span><span class="hidden">Less</span></div>');

$('.content').on('click', '.showbutton', function() {
   $(this).prev('.moreless').toggleClass('less');
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.less {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden {
     display: none;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrvtw/

You would need to put some checks in to make sure you aren't adding a `more` button when the content is smaller than the container.

Comment: Because my code is already a bit more advanced with much more things to take into account, the above example is not directly usable, but it is a very welcome guidance to get the way of working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way could be to keep a short and long version rather than a first and second part and on click of a button just swap between the two:

```
var content =  $heroContent.html();
c = content.substr(0, 700)

html = "<div class='short'>" + c + "</div>" + 
       "<div class='all'>" + content + "</div>";

mybutton.toggle() -> $('.short').hide();
                     $('.all').show(); // and viceversa on second click.
```

How does that sound?

Comment: Sounds pretty good indeed! But there needs to be a transition between the two states, so you actually see the text slide down and up..